# Deck diagonal bracing alternatives

Tags: deck, code-compliance

The IRC prescriptive deck guide calls for decks taller than 6' to have diagonal bracing placed parallel (planar) to the beam from post to beam.

My deck, which is built with a beam on one side and a house-anchored ledger-board on the other, with joists running perpendicular to the ledger/beam, currently has this diagonal bracing running from beam to post. However, I am planning on screening in the underside of my deck and do not want the bracing there. I am looking for alternatives. I was told that I could run the deck boards diagonally instead, but my deck surface is already in place and I do not want to redeck the entire structure.

Are there other alternatives, such as a prefabricated bracket I could buy to replace the bracing?

Comment: If it's a diagonal brace running from post to beam, it won't be parallel to the beam. ;-)  The reason for the angled brace is that it forms a triangular structure in the same plane, which is very stable and will prevent the the tall posts from tipping. This means you need at least one diagonal brace on each side of each plane (each vertical face of the deck). I'm pretty sure I don't believe that diagonally-arranged decking would stabilize the uprights, because that would only reinforce the shape of the top of the deck (one plane).

Comment: The diagonal bracing is there for a reason. Leave it in place.

Comment: @Craig Bracing from post to beam is parallel to the beam. Bracing from post to joist is perpendicular to the beam, but is optional in a house-supported deck according to the prescriptive guide.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Diagonal bracing serves a purpose, but there's many ways to accomplish the same bracing. I'm just looking for an alternative.

Comment: @Craig According to the prescriptive guide, "If the deck is attached to the house as shown in Figures 14, 15, 16, or 23, an alternative to knee braces for deck stability (Figure 22) is installation of decking at a 45 degree angle to the deck joists. Decks are stiffer laterally with diagonally oriented lumber decking versus decking installed perpendicular to joists."

Comment: Well *that* definitely makes sense. If it's attached to the house, then the house itself is stabilizing the sides of the deck. That still wouldn't keep it from tipping/twisting to the sides, but the diagonal deck planks *would* accomplish that, because the top rectangular frame of the deck would not be able to deform. Your original post didn't specify attaching the back edge of the deck to the house.

Comment: @DavidPfeffer Sorry, but I'm not picturing the distinction you're making between post-to-beam and post-to-joist. Parallel means that two lines run to infinity in both directions without ever touching. If there's any angle at all between the lines, they are not parallel. The joists may sit across the beams at a 90° angle (perpendicular), but any support running from a post to a beam *or* a joist will still be at an angle and create a triangle, thus *not* parallel.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelKaras, any box shape is going to be unstable without angled support. That includes your house. One of the reasons your house is as stable as it (presumably) is, is because of shear wall design, where plywood or oxboard panels secured across multiple studs create the same kind of lateral stability that a triangular (angled) brace would create. There actually are **not** all that many ways to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @Craig I think we're arguing semantics. The lines created by the beam and the diagonal brace are not parallel rays. However in 3D, objects that are planar (i.e. exist in the same plane) are often just called parallel. That's what the guide means when they indicate parallel vs perpendicular diagonal bracing.

Comment: @Craig I agree in part with what you're saying. However, "unstable" is of course a relative term. Any deck will be laterally unstable given the right amount of force; the bracing just seeks to dramatically increase the amount of force required before failure. The diagonal bracing _should_ be able to be replaced with a sufficiently sized metal bracket of some sort, because the bracket's substantially increased material rigidity would overcome any real-world forces.

Comment: Simpson Strong-Tie seems to sells a bracket, http://www.strongtie.com/products/connectors/KBS.asp, that shows one installation option with 45 degree diagonal bracing and another installation option without it, instead placing the brackets at the beam/post interface. It provides a load table for both uplift and lateral force and a code certification to that effect. Assuming all of the solutions provide adequate beam/post anchoring to prevent uplift, is lateral force the only thing I care about w.r.t. the diagonal bracing? Or is there another force to which I should pay attention?

Comment: FWIW this isn't a settled issue. The prescriptive guide doesn't even totally know what they're doing yet. In the 2009 guide, it required all post/beam joints to have diagonal bracing. In the 2012 guide, it now _forbids_ any non-end post/beam joists to have diagonal bracing.

Comment: Hi David, I agree that "unstable" is a matter of definition within a set of requirements. If whatever you do, doesn't stiffen the deck up enough that it can't easily be deformed into a rhombus, then it just won't be safe. You know what, though? I wonder if you could put diagonals flat across the bottoms of the joists?

Comment: As Craig pointed out, you could install diagonal bracing on the underside of your deck joists.  It still wouldn't be fully up to code, but it would address the potential to twist about as well as redecking with diagonal boards.

Comment: @Bob Why wouldn't that be up to code?

Comment: @DavidPfeffer I'm just curious (genuinely) if you ever resolved this? Like you, I'm not sure why diagonals across the bottoms of the joists wouldn't be up to code if diagonals across the tops are. I mean, you would screw them in place, so it isn't as if they'd fall off or anything...  ;-)

Comment: @Craig I ended up going with those brackets. All keeping something square means is sufficient lateral bracing, and those brackets do brace with sufficient force to withstand wind > 100 MPH and live loads as simulated by several university studies I found.

Comment: @DavidPfeffer The Simpson metal braces? If they're tested and approved they should certainly do the job!

Comment: @Craig They're tested for a certain lateral load; there's no deck code beyond "sufficient" for lateral load in IRC.